# WindowsMediaPlayer openPlayer and playlist C#

Tags: c#, playlist, wmp

I use WindowsMediaPlayer wmp, but i can't launch WMP (open window) and add items in current play list;

- I can openPlayer(mediaPath);
  OR
- I can load a new playlist with :

  ```
  IWMPMedia m = wmp.newMedia(pathNameFile1);
  wmp.currentPlaylist.appendItem(m);
  IWMPMedia m2 = wmp.newMedia(pathNameFile2);
  wmp.currentPlaylist.appendItem(m2);
  wmp.controls.play();
  ```

=> but not both in the same time.

Sorry for my english
Thanks for your help

Anthony